# How can I load two data tables in one page using struts?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, struts

Im using struts 1.3 + spring 2.5 + hibernate 3.

I have two tables: category and product.

Im using tags-logic to load data from category.

```
<logic:iterate id="cat" name="catList">
    <bean:write name="cat" property="catName" />
</logic:iterate>
```

But when I use tags-logic again to load data from product in same page

```
<logic:iterate id="pro" name="proList">
    <bean:write name="pro" property="proName" />
</logic:iterate>
```

it errors, and throw Exception: << Cannot find bean: "proList" in any scope >>

How can I resolve it? I want to load two data table from database in one page. Please help me.

Comment: Please share your Action Code, where you have populated proList and catList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Action class should have code something like this, i think you have missed to add proList in request.

try below code

```
public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) {           

     List<Category> catList = db.getCategory();           
     List<Product> proList = db.getProduct();           

     request.setAttribute("proList", proList);      
     request.setAttribute("catList ", catList );      
     return mapping.findForward("success");  
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I missed List<Product> proList = db.getProduct(); request.setAttribute("proList", proList);